# Two different WritableCellFormat for a single label or cel

Tags: java, excel, formatting, format, jxl

I'm writing to write print two text's in the same cell with different WritableCellFormat format, its shown below

```
lable = new Label(0, 1, "Market: "+someValue,tableHeaderCellFormat);
sheet.addCell(lable);
sheet.mergeCells(0, 1, 0, 1);
```

Here `Market:` is like label ,it'll remain same , but `someValue` is dynamic,
I want `Market:` to be in bold and `someValue` in normal font style ie. not bold, I want to write both of 'em in the same cell. Any help?

Comment: are you using apache poi?

Comment: As tagged it is JExcel API. And how mentioned in its [FAQ](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/) (scroll down till last point "Does JXL support feature XXXXXX?") it cannot deal with Rich Text as cell content.

Comment: @SpringLearner No..I'm not using POI